# Monitoring applications on Zabbix

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

everyone, I am trying to monitor an application for transactions on Zabbix, I have already installed the agent on the windows server where the application is running on. However, I only get stats such as CPU, disk space, networks etc. I am trying to monitor transactions and interfaces. How do I go about?

Comment: If you can get information about transactions and interfaces (whatever that means) through the command line, consider using user parameters (see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/userparameters).

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using user parameters if you want pure zabbix solution.  Have your application transactions output status, and capture that.  This approach can be cumbersome.

If you are not looking for pure zabbix solution I would look at a solution that supports transactional monitoring, something like http://wdt.io .

Comment: I Agree with @Fiala. Zabbix is not meant for that. [Transactional monitoring](http://pandorafms.com/monitoring-solutions/business-activity-monitoring/) on Pandora FMS is pretty awesome. [See this screenshot](http://pandorafms.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/bpm_view_6.0SP1_sinmarco.jpg). It's in Spanish, but they also have an English version.